# Apply a function to every single React Component

Tags: reactjs

I need to add the following in `componentDidMount()` in every single react Component.

Code to add:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

How can I do that without writting it in each component?

Comment: If you want to set this on every route change, just listen the event in parent component and set window.scrollTo(0, 0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using react-router, you can create a ScrollToTop component :

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
    import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

    const ScrollToTop = ({ children, location: { pathname } }) => {
      useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo({
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          behavior: "smooth"
        });
      }, [pathname]);

      return children || null;
    };

    export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

And wrap your app in it :

```
<Router>
        <ScrollToTop>
           <App />
        </ScrollToTop>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- First make component with name ScrollToTop.js
like this:

```
import {Component} from "react";
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

class ScrollToTop extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {location} = this.props;
    if (location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {children} = this.props;
    return children;
  }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

2- Then import and use in Parent Component source where all child component needed scrolling like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import FirstChild from './FirstChild';
import SecondChild from './SecondChild';

import ScrollToTop from './ScrollToTop';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop>
         <Route path = "/first" component = {FirstChild} />
         <Route path = "/second" component = {SecondChild} />
         </Switch>
      </ScrollToTop>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is extremely unlikely you actually want what you think you want, but nonetheless it is possible, if a bit uncomfortable.

just extend the `React.Component` and use that instead of `React.Component`

```
class ScrollComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount(...args) {
    console.log('listen!')
  }
}

// later..
class RandomComponent extends ScrollComponent {

  render() {}
}
```

do note, that if you want to add more behavior to component did mount you will have to invoke `super` so to not override the behavior.

```
class ComponentWithOnMount extends ScrollComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    doThing()
    super.componentDidMount() // <-- invokes window.scroll(0,0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Avoid the use of inheritance, See https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: @lissettdm I agree, but do consider the requirement. with *every* component needing this componentDidMount without wrapping everything in a HOC or some parent

Comment: The recommendation is to use composition before inheritance, and in this case the composition is possible.

Comment: this would break the restriction placed by OP, *How can I do that without writting it in each component?*, since he would need to write it in each component. whether the lifecycle hook or wrapping component. The question itself has a major flaw with it asking something that doesn't make sense. I just answered the best way to fulfill all the conditions required by the asker

Comment: He doesn't need to add this in every component, I know the questions says that, but the problem can be solve wrapping this on some parent component, only one component.